# hasMany/belongsTo: how do i change the ownership of an item (move from one parent to another)?

Tags: ember.js

I've got a model that is both `hasMany` and `belongsTo` related to itself

```
Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
  parent: DS.belongsTo('todo', {inverse: 'children'}),
  children: DS.hasMany('todo', {inverse: 'parent'})
});
```

I am going to let the user drag-n-drop todos on each other to let him rearrange the hierarchy. But that's a difficult task for a person not familiar with Ember, so i decided to start with something simpler:

Each todo contains a dropdown list of possible parents. A user can select any parent from the list and the todo gets updated with that parent.

There's also a "no parent" item in the dropdown list. When it is selected for a todo, this todo is updated to contain no parent.

The way i perform the modification of the parent of a todo is pretty straightforward:

1. Grab a collection of models from the Todos ArrayController (`controllers.todos.model`).
2. Filter the collection so that it contains only a record with an id equal to the requested id (from user's choice on the dropdown list).
3. Grab the first and only record from the filtered collection.
4. Set the current record's `parent` field` to the grabbed record object.
5. Save the currrent record.

I have also created a couple of simple properties on the todo controller to see whether each  todo has a parent and children:

```
  hasChildren: (function() {
    return this.get('model.children').get('length') > 0;
  }).property('model.parent', 'model.children'),

  hasParent: (function() {
    return this.get('model.parent') !== null;
  }).property('model.parent', 'model.children'),
```

From the `hasParent` property i can tell that the parent does get modified when i change a todo's parent using the dropdown list, yay! The modification persists through page refreshes (i'm using the Local Storage adapter), so i assume that i perform updating todo's parent correctly.

The problem is that the `hasChildren` property on todo B is not udpated when i update the 'parent' property on todo A to contain todo B. This prevents me from automatically refreshing the hierarchy of todos on the page.

I used to believe that Ember Data should automatically update the `children` property on the parent when i update the `parent` property on the child. That's what the `inverse` thingie is for, right? If Ember Data is not supposed to automatically maintain the integrity of the relationship, why would it want to know the opposite properties of the relationship?

So either i'm wrong and i should manually update the `children` property of the old and new parents when i update the `parent` property on the child todo (risking to damage the integrity of relationships), or i'm changing the parent in a wrong way.

The question is: what is the correct way of changing the ownership of an item in a hasMany/belongsTo relationship?

Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/UDoPajA/220/edit

### UPD1 for ppcano:

I've tried your approach and it made no difference. :( I have applied your suggestions, and the model `hasParent` property does get updated dynamically. But the `haschildren` property doesn't.

But then i tried setting the `hasChildren` property to observe `todos.@each.parent` and it started to update, yay!

What i still don't understand: in order to change relation of a record i have to do a lot of work. This is how i applied your suggestion:

```
var model = this.get('model');

// Removing current todo from the list of children of the former parent
model
  .get('parent')
  .get('children')
  .removeObject(model);

// Adding current todo to the list of children of the new parent
this
  .get('todos')
  .filter( function(candidateTodo) {
    return candidateTodo.get('id') === newParentId;
  })[0]
  .pushObject(model);

model.save();
```

This is a hell lot of work and is also more prone to breaking the integrity of relationships. Why can't i do this instead?

```
var model = this.get('model');
var newParent = this
  .get('todos')
  .filter( function(candidateTodo) {
    return candidateTodo.get('id') === newParentId;
  })[0];

model.set('parent', newParent);
model.save();
```

I've tried that and it won't work. :( The parent property gets updated, but the children property won't.

Is there a way to properly update the relationship from the `belognsTo` end rather than doing extra job to update the relationship from the `hasMany` end.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18196693/901944) but it basically means manual updating on both ends and i don' like it either. The asker there also surprised that Ember requires doing that manually.

There's a weirder thing. In order to update current model's `parent` property, we have to modify the relationship on the opposite end (call a method on the `children` property on the parent). If we do it on the parent, why it is required to do `.save()` on the current model and not the parent model in order for changes to persist? And why does the `hasChildren` property have to observe `todos.@each.parent` and observing `model.children` does not work?

There's also another unsolved problem: when a new todo is added or an existing todo is deleted, the "Parent:" dropdown lists of all todos would reset to the "no parent" state! But if i refresh the page, the correct parent selection in dropdowns is restored. Whaaat?

Please help me resolve these issues. Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/UDoPajA/231/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you setup the `inverse` property, you only need to push/remove objects from the relationship and ember-data will take care to update the dependent relationship.

```
parent.get('children').then(function(children){
  children.removeObject(child);
})

parent.get('children').then(function(children){
  children.pushObject(child);
})
```

Because of the current status of ember-data (using v1.0.0-beta.8), you could define your `hasParent` and `hasChildren` as:

```
  hasChildren: Ember.computed.notEmpty('children.[]'),
  hasParent: Ember.computed.notEmpty('parent.content')
```

Look at this example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pubij/2/edit

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @ppcano. It helped, but i still struggle with issues. Please have a look at my udpated question and reply in as much detail as you can. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my response and example to create hasParent and hasChildren CP correctly. Take in consideration that I am using async:true in the relationship, this will be the default way in the final release and because of that, you must access as a promise: this.get('parent').then.   I would recommend, you splits your doubts in multiple SO isolated questions, it is difficult to follow other developer implementations and try to solve different issues at the same time.